# sudo: command not found when I ssh into server

Tags: linux, ssh, server, laravel-5, sudo

I am a newbie with server handling and Linux. I am trying to install composer on my server so that i can host my Laravel project onto it as mentioned in the tutorial in [Ultimate Guide: Deploy Laravel 5.3 App on LEMP Stack](https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/). I **ssh** into the server and after installation of composer when I run `sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` I am getting a message in the terminal:

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

I desperately need some deliberate help

Comment: Are you sshing into the server as `root` per chance?

Comment: If not, have you tried googling it? Seems like this is a very common problem.

Comment: no i am not sshin into the server as root.. I tried googling but not able to figure out a correct solution

Comment: It looks like `sudo` is just not installed or not in your path.

Comment: what shal i do @nsilent22 ??

Comment: 1. su to root; 2. apt-get install sudo

Comment: did you tyr to run /usr/bin/sudo to see if it's in your path? It's unusual not have sudo installed.  What OS (run cat /proc/version) ?

Comment: @mdo123 i ran cat/proc/version i got a message as not such file of directory

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sudo is probably not installed or not in your path

1. check to see if you are `root` in this case sudo is not needed unless you are trying to impersonate another user. just run your command without sudo `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer`
2. See if sudo is your path by running `which sudo` or `echo $PATH`. If sudo is not in your path, your path variable might be broken. You can try testing this by executing a common location for sudo `/usr/bin/sudo` or running `locate sudo | grep bin` to attempt to find its location.
3. If you know that sudo was installed, or your path looks broken, try fixing your path. Check your distribution's env file (/etc/environment in ubuntu) to make sure that it is formatted correctly (script commands are illegal in this file)
4. If you are not `root` and you want to run a command with root prvileges then you must install sudo. But if you don't have sudo and you are not root then you can't install it. In this case I recommend switching to the root user with `su`
5. If you do not have the root password and you own the machine, you can reset the root password with a tutorial such as https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password
6. After you manage to login as root install sudo with `apt-get update; apt-get install sudo`since you are using Ubuntu.
7. Verify the the name of your sudoers group with `visudo` and modify your sudoers file if you need to. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos
8. if you have an existing sudoers group or you create one you can add yourself to the group. For example if your sudoers group is called sudo run `usermod -aG sudo myuser`. The sudoers group by default in Ubuntu based Linux is sudo. A sudoers group entry looks like this: `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`

If you are trying to impersonate another user and cannot install sudo, you can still use `su` if it is installed and you have permission / password for the other user.

e.g. `su someuser`

Comment: when i am using mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer without sudo i get a message as permission not available

Comment: @SurajJeswara what is the exact comand you are using to connect with ssh? which login are you using?

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291993/sudo-command-not-found-when-following-a-tutorial-for-lets-encrypt), you may have to install sudo in your server.

To do that, log in as root with the following command: `su -`. Then install `sudo` with your package manager (if you're in Ubuntu: `apt-get install sudo`).

Then add your user to the `sudo` group: `usermod -aG sudo <username>`.

Finally type `exit` to log out of the root account and go back to your user.

Answer (score 1):

try to install your sudo using by first logging in as a root(su - ) and then try to install **apt-get or yum sudo **. Make sure your path variable is set so that you would be able to get binary.

**which sudo**

**echo $PATH**